# Configure environment variable with Neo4j and docker-compose

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am packing my application into jar and run it with Docker using bash script (which executes jar). I would like to change neo4j database url configuration as environment variable in docker-compose file, however, I still get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$NotResolved: neo4j.url has not been resolved, you need to call Config#resolve(), see API docs for Config#resolve()
```

How can I solve this problem and where should I add some configurations for that?

I have only set up url variable in configurations file:

```
neo4j{
    url= "bolt://localhost:7687"
    url = ${?HOSTNAME}
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
}
```

Also, I use this variable in configurations method:

```
  def getNeo4jConfig(configName: String) = {
    val neo4jLocalConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("configs/local_neo4j.conf"))
    neo4jLocalConfig.resolve()

    val driver = configName match {
      case "neo4j_local" => GraphDatabase.driver(neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.url"),
        AuthTokens.basic(neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.user"), neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.password")))
      case _ => GraphDatabase.driver("url", AuthTokens.basic("user", "password"))
    }

    driver.session
  }
```

In docker-compose.yml I defined the value of the hostname:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  neo4j_db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/neo4j/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/conf:/neo4j/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/neo4j/logs
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_active__database=graphImport.db
  benchmarks:
    image: "container"
    volumes:
      - ./:/workdir1
    working_dir: /workdir1
    links:
      - neo4j_db
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=myhoat
```

Also, bash script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for run in {1..2}
do
    java -cp "target/scala-2.11/benchmarking.jar" benchmarks/Main $1 $2
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined hostname as arg in Dockerfile and then defined it in docker-compose file for the application build. That solved the problem!

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  benchmarks-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - HOST=neo4jdb
    volumes:
      - ./:/workdir
    working_dir: /workdir
```

Dockerfile args definition:

```
FROM java:8
ARG HOST
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.8
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.1.1
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.2.0
ENV SPARK_DIST spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.6
ENV SPARK_ARCH $SPARK_DIST.tgz
ENV NEO4J_CONFIG $DB_CONFIG
ENV BENCHMARK $BENCHMARK_NAME
ENV HOSTNAME bolt://$HOST:7687
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Set these env in a `.env` file in the same location than your
>   docker-compose.yml file:

**.env**

```
VAR1=value
VAR2=2.0
VAR3=`awk -F ':' '{if ($3 == 1000) {print $1}}' /etc/passwd` <-- any bash command, for example
...
```

And for example, use them in your compose file sections:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile_${VAR2}
...
```

Comment: Should I add some env to the Dockerfile itself?

Comment: Yes, you can add them to the Dockerfile, but ENV defined in dockerfile will be accesible only for entrypoint. The same if you set them in `environment:` section of the docker-compose.yml file